# What thread is unSubscribeOn called? Should we call it?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

What thread is unsubscribeOn defaulted to when we do not specify it but still specify the thread for subscribeOn?
Are we required to specify the thread that we want un-subscription to happen on even when it is the same thread as the one used in subscribeOn?

Or are the bottom two snippets doing the same for un-subscription?

Option 1:

```
mSubscription.add(myAppProvider
        .getSomeData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(data -> handleData(data),
                throwable -> handleError(throwable)
                ));
```

Option 2:

```
mSubscription.add(myAppProvider
        .getSomeData()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(data -> handleData(data),
                throwable -> handleError(throwable)
                ));
```

I did look at the [Rx-Java docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) but they only explain subscribeOn but nothing about unSubscribeOn

Answer (score 4):

Without `subscribeOn` (and without `observeOn`), your unsubscription actions will occur on whatever thread the subscription started.

With `subscribeOn`, your unsubscription actions will occur on the Scheduler specified by `subscribeOn`.

With `observeOn`, your unsubscription actions will occur on the Scheduler specified by `observeOn` (overriding the Scheduler specified by `subscribeOn`).

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%204%20-%20Concurrency/1.%20Scheduling%20and%20threading.md#unsubscribeon). As  suggested there, this is useful when the unsubscription itself involves long-running operations that you want to run on some other thread.

If you run their test code:

```
Observable<Object> source = Observable.using(
    () -> {
        System.out.println("Subscribed on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return Arrays.asList(1,2);
    },
    (ints) -> {
        System.out.println("Producing on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return Observable.from(ints);
    },
    (ints) -> {
        System.out.println("Unubscribed on " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
);

source
    .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

You should see their expected output:

```
 Subscribed on 1
 Producing on 1
 1
 2
 Unubscribed on 11
```

If you remove that `unsubscribeOn` line, you'll see:

```
 Unsubscribed on 1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I like your explanation of the threads that unSubscribeOn is happening on. However this example doesn't work the way you showed in my sample that I created to test. For me unsubscribe is also happening on the same thread. '1'. Want to fix your code so that I can accept it? Another this is that the 'docs' you mentioned is actually a sample. not real Rx-Java docs. The real docs are here http://reactivex.io/intro.html.

Comment: Ah good catch - yep, definitely not the real docs.  Can you post the full code you're using to check the thread?

Comment: Yeah, I will add as a separate answer so that you may use that to update your answer. Or may be fix it if I am doing any mistake in my approach :)

Comment: Hey drhr, Do you think the example is still valid? I tried it a few times and it always says that unsubscribed on thread 1. Mind updating the answer so that I can accept this? Thank you.

Comment: I would but I'm not clear on what you're seeing. The results you posted seem consistent with what I posted, yet you're reporting a different result, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: In your result you said unsubscribed on thread is '11' but I see that as 1 regardless of unsubscribedOn is set to a new thread or not.

Comment: doesn't seem like unsubscribe is called from the scheduler used in subscribeOn. @dave-moten answer seems more accurate.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing. The question asked what happens when `unsubscribeOn` is not specified.

Answer (score 4):

Those snippets have different behaviours.

In general, unsubscription travels up the operator sequence and can be initiated by any thread at all (just call `subscriber.unsubscribe()` from any thread). Without the presence of an `unsubscribeOn` operator the unsubscribe action will probably complete its action on the thread it was called from. `unsubscribeOn` provides finer control of the thread used for unsubscription upstream of it.

Answer (score 2):

> What thread is unsubscribeOn defaulted to when we do not specify it
>   but still specify the thread for subscribeOn?

- By default when neither of subscribeOn/observeOn/unsubscribeOn are
  set, then unsubscribeOn (as well as others) are defaulted to the
  current thread.
- If we do set a thread for subscribeOn and none for
  observeOn/unsubscribeOn, then unsubscribeOn will use the same thread
  specified in subscribeOn.
- If we call both subscribeOn and ObserveOn but not unsubscribeOn, then
  unsubscribeOn will use the thread specified in observeOn.
- If all three methods (subscribeOn, observeOn and unsubscribeOn) are
  set, then unsubscribeOn will use the thread specified in
  unsubscribeOn. In fact unsubscribeOn will happen on the thread
  specified in unsubscribeOn method regardless of weather the previous
  methods are set or not.

> Are we required to specify the thread that we want un-subscription to
>   happen on even when it is the same thread as the one used in
>   subscribeOn?

- As explained above if unsubscribeOn is not set then unsubscribeOn
  happens on observeOn if it is set. If not then it happens on the
  thread set by subscribeOn. Now we do not need to set a different
  thread for unsubscribeOn unless you are doing some long running task
  while unsubscribing. In most cases or atleast from my code, this is
  true and so we do not have to set a different thread.

Here is a sample that I created that can be used to test the above in Android. Just comment out or change the threads as required to test various outcomes.

```
    public void testRxThreads() {
        createThreadObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(printResult());
    }

    private Observable<String> createThreadObservable() {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            subscriber.add(new Subscription() {
                @Override
                public void unsubscribe() {
                    System.out.println("UnSubscribe on Thread: "
                        + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    // perform unsubscription
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isUnsubscribed() {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            subscriber.setProducer(n -> {
                System.out.println("Producer thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });

            subscriber.onNext("Item 1");
            subscriber.onNext("Item 2");
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        });
    }

    private Action1<String> printResult() {
        return result -> {
            System.out.println("Subscriber thread: "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        };
    }
```

This produced the following result

```
Producer thread: 556 RxIoScheduler-2
Subscriber thread: 1 main
Result: Item 1
Subscriber thread: 1 main
Result: Item 2
UnSubscribe on Thread: 557 RxNewThreadScheduler-1
```

Commenting out or removing unsubscribeOn produces the following.

```
Subscriber thread: 1 main
Result: Item 1
Subscriber thread: 1 main
Result: Item 2
UnSubscribe on Thread: 1 main
```

Removing out both observeOn and unsubscribeOn calls produce the following:

```
Producer thread: 563 RxIoScheduler-2
Subscriber thread: 563 RxIoScheduler-2
Result: Item 1
Subscriber thread: 563 RxIoScheduler-2
Result: Item 2
UnSubscribe on Thread: 563 RxIoScheduler-2
```

Thanks to drhr for the initial explanation of events. That helped me research more and verify the outcomes with the sample above.

Comment: That all looks right. What's different about your results?

Comment: Oh the problem I had was that the example shown in the sample you linked to claims that Unubscribed on happens on the thread specified in unSubscribeOn but I couldn't get that to work for me. Instead it just happened on the thread that subscribeOn uses. I did this with your sample to play with it. source
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println); That said that subscription and unsubscription happened on the same thread 'Unubscribed on 564 RxIoScheduler-3'

Comment: Oh and even when I did not call subscribeOn and just specify a thread in unsubscribeOn, it was not using a new thread. Instead everything was happening from the same thread. 1 instead of 11 as the thread id in your answer.